# Selecting training container for custom training

Tags: artificial-intelligence, google-cloud-vertex-ai

I'm trying to to start the a custom training of a new model with vertex ai, but the step "Training Container" is not showing up in my interface anymore. How do I define the training container?

I've been trying to select a training container for a custom training

Comment: Can you share a screenshot of your interface? If you're working with the GUI, you need to select the tab "CUSTOM JOBS" bevor you click "+ TRAIN NEW MODEL".